# CoreData NSPredicate with BOOL comparison not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, magicalrecord

I'am going crazy over this

```
items = [Item MR_findAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.userData.checklisted = NO"]];
```

Should return only items, which clearly have self.userData.checklisted NO, but when i debug right after this line execution, i get

```
(lldb) po [[standItems[0] userData] checklisted]
0

(lldb) po [[standItems[1] userData] checklisted]
1
```

So an item with self.userData.checklisted = YES is returned (althrough the predicate was self.userData.checklisted = NO)

**What is the cause of this behaviour? How to make it work?**

**UPDATE**
I found that the issues was that the item was unsaved, but how to make it work with unsaved data too?

Comment: have you tried using `==` instead of `=`. also the `self` is redundant and you don't need it. Failing this you could always use the block matcher if it is a complex query but I don't believe this is the case.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson `==` and `=` are the same NSPredicate comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `+ (NSArray *) MR_findAllWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchTerm inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context` method (instead of the one you are currently using), and pass the context that contains the changes that have not yet been saved.

Comment: nope, i dont see a difference there, as when you drill down in "MR_findAllWithPredicate:" you will find it calls MR_findAllWithPredicate: inContext:[self MR_defaultContext]... and MR_defaultContext is the with unsaved changes

Comment: @PeterLapisu Are you sure? I am not familiar with MR, but I am familiar with Core Data, and when executing a `NSFetchRequest` on a context with changes, the changes are also consulted.

Comment: as from my test, i got back [[standItems[1] userData] checklisted]
== 1, right after execution... this stop to happened when i saved to Persistent store (MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait)! strangle, saving to the MOC only with MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait also returned checklisted == 1